# How to Display Kilometer format on x-axis along with multiple yaxis data in Jquery High Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I try to display `kilometer` data on `x-axis` in high chart,it's display but problem is that not splice properly,

please check jsfiddle to clear idea http://jsfiddle.net/oxfh0wdp/1/,

i exactly like this http://jsfiddle.net/v55bcghp/1/ by using put x-axis data in categories key without fractional point

How achieve this ?

Comment: try this .... http://jsfiddle.net/oxfh0wdp/1/

Comment: i had try this already but problem is that not fractional point are display, I want like this `0Km 1Km 2Km 3Km` etc....slicing would be automatically due to data

Comment: i want exactly like this check links http://tinyurl.com/ou7cz3x   amit_183

Comment: You can use tickInterval and then label format to add km. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/25dyfh1b/

Comment: thank you for replay i have find out myself, yes i can also put tickinterval but there is static display i want to display dynamically splice of km not 1km 2km etc...

Comment: Ok, I have read your question twice and I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. Could you attach screenshot of the desired result? I guess you want to display x-axis-label in the same places as point are? Then use `tickPositioner`: http://jsfiddle.net/v55bcghp/2/ (I suggest to filter out very close values, like 0 and 1.9). If that's not the case, then please, provide mockup/screenshot what you want to achieve - thanks!

Comment: see i have changed your code http://jsfiddle.net/v55bcghp/3/ check link

Comment: also check following link of polar https://flow.polar.com/training/analysis/112845946 change setting to distance,then you get idea what did i said thank

Comment: Ok, you changed my demo, still I asked for a better description or mockup - is that demo what you need to achieve? In the second link, I changed the distance, but unfortunately I didn't get the idea..

Comment: i have resolved that issue